# RStudio can't install "igraph" - C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, igraph

Im using anaconda, so RStudio 1.1.456.

When I try to

```
install.packages("igraph")
```

I get this message:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/igraph_1.2.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2704004 bytes (2.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
** package ‘igraph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/x1/zlhhtxm951v95d461h7d09bc0000gn/T/Rtmp0iNakh/R.INSTALL16a5d3eb16782/igraph':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/Users/RobinHorn/anaconda3/envs/Data_Analysis/lib/R/library/igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/x1/zlhhtxm951v95d461h7d09bc0000gn/T/RtmpYbzkOw/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

So it looks like my C compiler is not working.

**What I tried already:**

installing command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

installing missing headers:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

This results in:

```
installer: Error - the package path specified was invalid: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg'.
```

gcc seems to be installed correctly:

```
~ % gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your post because I had the same problem.  My answer hinges on one question:  do you really need to access RStudio through Anaconda?  If your answer is "no," then the solution is simple:

I downloaded RStudio from rstudio.com and installed it directly on my Mac; the version happens to be 1.2.5033.  Now when I install

```
install.packages("igraph")
```

everything works fine.  I have tested several functions with no problem (but don't forget to load the package).

Note that when I return to RStudio through Anaconda, it still does not work.  Apparently, Anaconda keeps its own copy of the install tree but does not play nicely with certain packages ...